# want to delete a task from an array of object using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have an array(tasks) of objects in my model. I want to delete a task from the array using sequelize and save back to db(postgresql). Here i am trying to find the index of the task which will deleted and update the tasks in my db. but change is not visible to my db. Here is my code:

```
        var idx=0;
        for(var i=0;i<user.tasks.length;i++){
            if(user.tasks[i].task_id==req.params.task_id){
                idx=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        user.tasks.splice(idx,1);
        user.update({
            tasks:user.tasks
        }).then((user)=>{
            res.redirect("/seq/task/allTask")
        })
    })
```

Comment: `user.tasks.task_id` should be `user.tasks[i].task_id`?

Comment: @D.Seah yes it should be this but it still not working

Comment: If this is an array, you can use modern array methods like findIndex https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: Or even better, filter: `const itemIdToRemove = req.params.task_id; user.tasks = user.tasks.filter(t => t.task_id != itemIdToRemove);`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @ChrisBaker my for loop for index finding works fine but after the user.update() is not working. Actually after user.update().then((user)=>{console.log(user.tasks)}) also works fine but the changes is not updated in database

Comment: So it's some kind of problem with the db thing -- I didn't post an answer because I am not familiar. However, the foreach loop stuff is very "old school" -- check out those links I posted :)

Answer (score 1):

inside `user.update()` use this `{tasks:Sequelize.fn('array_remove',Sequelize.col('tasks'),JSON.stringify(user.tasks[i]))}`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let user_id = 2 
let pinned_by_user = [1,2,4,5]
 let i = pinned_by_user.indexOf(user_id);
      if (pinned_by_user > -1)                                                  
               {
              pinned_by_user.splice(i, 1);
               } 
 ViewLog.update({ 'pinned_by_user': db.sequelize.fn('array_remove',db.sequelize.col('pinned_by_user'), user_id) },{ 'where': { 'questionId': question_id } })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Community Bot did't like answers with only code without explanation, please add some explanetion for other users

Comment: It is working.Solved my bug